# Failed mined transactions

Tags: transactions, blocks

Is transaction "status" flagged inside the block when it's mined?

Like if a transaction is mined but failed due to out of gas or not meeting contract conditions, is the transaction marked as "failed" as part of the raw hexadecimal block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction `status` is part of the transaction `receipt` that is stored locally by the nodes in the `transaction receipt trie`. The block header includes a reference to the receipt trie called the `receiptsRoot` which is a hash of the root node of the trie.

All transactions included in the block, failed or successful, have an impact on the block hash.